# Translating Database Models to Models on Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, entity-relationship, relational-model

I am beginning Ruby On Rails through a purchase/resale platform project at school. I'm having an issue with my models when I try to translate them from my relational model.

Firstly, I've modelled my database. Here is simplified the entity-relationship model :

[image: Entity-relationship model]

I've then translated it in a relational model :

[image: Relational model]

Finally, I've implemented it in Ruby On Rails.

- I've implemented a model Client :

  ```
  class Client < ApplicationRecord
      attr_accessor :name

      validates :name, :presence => true

      has_many :purchasings, :dependent => :destroy

      has_many :sellers, :through => :purchasings
      has_many :articles, :through => :purchasings
  end
  ```
- I've implemented a model Seller :

  ```
  class Seller < ApplicationRecord
      attr_accessor :name

      validates :name, :presence => true

      has_many :purchasings, :dependent => :destroy

      has_many :sellers, :through => :purchasings
      has_many :articles, :through => :purchasings
  end
  ```
- I've implemented a model Article

  ```
  class Article < ApplicationRecord
      attr_accessor :quantity

      validates :quantity, :presence => true

      has_one :purchasing, :dependent => :destroy

      has_one :client, :through => :purchasings
      has_one :seller, :through => :purchasings
  end
  ```
- I've implemented a model Purchasing :

  ```
  class Purchasing < ApplicationRecord
      attr_accessor :client_id, :seller_id, :article_id

      belongs_to :client, :class_name => "Client"
      belongs_to :seller, :class_name => "Seller"
      belongs_to :article, :class_name => "Article"

      validates :client_id, :presence => true
      validates :seller_id, :presence => true
      validates :article_id, :presence => true
  end
  ```
- I've modified the Purchasing database migration :

  ```
  class CreatePurchasing < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
      def change
          [...]

          add_index :purchasings, :client_id
          add_index :purchasings, :seller_id
          add_index :purchasings, :article_id
          add_index :purchasings, [:client_id, :seller_id], :unique => true
      end

      def down
          [...]
      end
  end
  ```

I know this is incorrect because when I execute the following code on the Rails console :

```
cl1 = Client.create(:name => "John")
cl2 = Client.create(:name => "James")
sel1 = Seller.create(:nom => "Jack")
sel2 = Seller.create(:nom => "Jil")
a1 = Article.create(:quantity => 5)

p1 = Purchasing.new(:client => cl1, :client_id => cl1.id, :seller => sel1, :seller_id => sel1.id, :article => a1, :article_id => a1.id)
p1.save
p2 = Purchasing.new(:client => cl2, :client_id => cl2.id, :seller => sel1, :seller_id => sel1.id, :article => a1, :article_id => a1.id)
p2.save
```

`p2.save` returns true whereas an article can't be sold by a same seller and bought by two clients different.

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: Also, drop the attr_accessors. They're not doing what you think they do.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Well, my test doesn't produce what I an expecting so I'm looking for a solution in order to have the correct behaviour (p2.save returning false because the article is already bought by a client).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Can you be more precise about atr_accessors ? What I have understood is that attr_accessors are equivalent to declaring getter/setter in Java ?

Comment: "are equivalent to declaring getter/setter in Java" - correct, but this is counter-productive here. You don't _need_ them in your models.  Declaring them overwrites getters/setters generated by active record. As a result, these properties won't get persisted.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Ok, thank you, I'm understanding ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the index on incorrect columns on purchasings table. As per the requirement, the article_id and seller_id should not get repeated ideally. So you actually need is a uniqueness constraint on seller_id, and article_id column. You can do so by creating an unique index on the composition of two columns seller_id, and article id on the database layer. You should also add the application layer validation on the purchasing model.

```
class Purchasing < ApplicationRecord
attr_accessor :client_id, :seller_id, :article_id

belongs_to :client, :class_name => "Client"
belongs_to :seller, :class_name => "Seller"
belongs_to :article, :class_name => "Article"

validates :client_id, :presence => true
validates :seller_id, :presence => true
validates :article_id, :presence => true

validates :article_id, uniqueness: {scope: :seller_id}
end
```

Now you should also write a database migration to add the unique index on these two columns.

```
    class AddUniquenessConstraintInPurshasing < ActiveRecord::Migration
       def change
         add_index :purchasings, [:article_id, :seller_id], :unique => true
    end
```

end

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.
`validates :article_id, uniqueness: {scope: :seller_id}` translates the fact that an article_id is unique for a given seller_id. Am I understanding right ?

Comment: It caters to the requirement of same seller not being able to sell the same article regardless of the amount of articles. This validation would not allow you the have any duplicate pair of article_id and seller_id in purchasing table. So I should rather say that one seller can sell one particular article only once. If your requirement is different, your design should change likewise. I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It clarifies everything. Finally, I think I should update my model as you say, it isn't so relevant